# Using two files to search/replace a third file

Tags: arrays, bash, file, sed

I have two files:
**correct.txt**

> the sky is blue
>   I like eat apple
>   .
>   .

and **wrong.txt**

> the sky are blue
>   I like eat apple
>   .
>   .
>   .

There are a lot of lines in both files.
Now, I want to correct a third file using my search in the "wrong.txt"
to correct it using the "correct.txt".

I have created two files:

```
readarray -t correct_array < correct.txt  
readarray -t wrong_array < wrong.txt
```

The file to be corrected is **to_be_corrected.txt**

This works:

```
for c in "${correct_array[@]}"
do
    echo "$c"
done
```

I tried this

```
for e in "${correct_array[@]}"
do
    sed -i.bak 's/$wrong_array[@]/$correct_array[@]/' to_be_corrected.txt
done
```

But this did not work.
How can I use `sed` with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using single quotes (`'`) for your `sed` command, so the shell is not evaluating the variables `$wrong_array[@]` and `$correct_array[@]`.  Try double quotes and braces on the variables.  Also, you are using the entire array with `${correct_array[@]}`.  You need to pair the elements together, perhaps with an index:

```
for ((e=0; e<"${#correct_array[@]}"; ++e)); do
    sed -i.bak "s/${wrong_array[$e]}/${correct_array[$e]}/" to_be_corrected.txt
done
```

This iterates `e` over the indexes of the array (`${#correct_array[@]}` gives the size of the array) then `e` is used to index the corresponding elements of `wrong_array` and `correct_array`.  Hopefully you don't have any quotes (single or double) in your text files.

Comment: Wait, do your `correct.txt` and `wrong.txt` files contain the entire sentence, or just the parts that need to be corrected?

Comment: Entire sentence. I want to correct a third file. The correct.txt and wrong.txt have the same sentences. The second the sentencers are wrong and in the first the senteces are corrected.

Comment: Your solution worked. I do not know why I can not give "green" to both solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `{}` with arrays. This doesn't work:

```
$array[1]
```

But this will:

```
${array[1]}
```

As pointed out by e0k you should also use double quoted otherwise the variable won't be expanded to it's actual value.

Don't know what exaclty your array has, but I think you want to iterate it instead of use the whole thing. Try this approach:

```
for i in `seq 0 $((${#correct_array[@]}-1))`; do
  sed -i.bak "s/${wrong_array[$i]}/${correct_array[$i]}/" to_be_corrected.txt
done
```